# conflicts between usr/lib, usr/local/lib and BLAKE2

Tags: 18.04, libraries, shared-library

I'm using a SEMECS library, a dependency is the libb2 BLACK2 library, I installed this library and it was installed successfully, but it was in `usr/local/lib` and it seems that SEMECS looks for it in `usr/lib`, so it generates the following error

`./semecs: error while loading shared libraries: libb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yeah that was the one D: sorry was a long day and I should stop makin comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. This is similar to $PATH, but for locating shared libraries.

Commonly, this is set in `~/.bashrc` :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib"
```

There is also the `ldd` command that lets you check what shared libs a binary uses (and from what paths):

```
ldd myprogram
```

e.g.

```
[sh @ balrog] ~ 7 % ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcdd75b000)
    libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x00007fa9ab768000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fa9ab540000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa9ab14f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa9aaf4b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa9aad2c000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa9aaaba000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa9abb91000)
```

Finally, there is `ldconfig` that recreates the linker cache for shared libraries; that is useful when you just built a new shared lib, and it might not be in the cache yet:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I think in this case, your second suggestion (executing `sudo ldconfig`) should be sufficient - and preferred - since `/usr/local/lib` is almost certainly already in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should really be a last resort.